# How to translate an attribute within html tag

Tags: angular, internationalization

Given a tag:

```
<a href="#" title="Translate me">Translate me</a>
```

How do I translate the attribute "title"?

The docs only describe how to translate the tag value itself:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mark any attribute for translation by adding `i18n-[attributeName]` to the tag:

```
<a href="#" title="Translate me" i18n-title>Translate me</a>
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/i18n/extractor_merger.ts lines 315-331 and 364-407

Comment: The documentation has been updated: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html#!#translate-attributes